# symfony webpack encore angularJS

Tags: angularjs, symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I made a migration from Symfony3.4 to SF4/Flex.
I was using assetic/bundle in SF3.4 but now I try to replace it with symfony/webpack-encore.

when I started using everything was okay but in my page I can't display the values returned in my webservice.

In my topTripsController a used a webservice to get a list of objects then I try to render them

```
<div ng-controller="topTripsController as homeNotLogged">            
<div data-ng-repeat="trip in homeNotLogged.trips track by $index" >
            <a ng-if="trip.cover.url " id="trip-||$index||">

                <h2 class="trip-title" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold" ng-bind="trip.name | capitalize">
                </h2>
                <div class="trip-date">
                    <span class="trip-title-first_name" ng-bind="trip.profile.name"> </span>
                    <span > · </span>
                    <span class="trip-title-from-date" ng-bind="trip.fromDate | date:'MMM, y'"> </span>
                </div>
            </a>
            </div>
    </div>

 {% block javascripts %}
     {{ parent() }}
     <script src="{{ absolute_url(asset('build/js/pages/index.js')) }}" ></script>

 {% endblock %}
```

when I write

```
{{trip }}
```

i got this result

```
 {"Id":15,"Profile":{"Id":2,"Name":"Alex Fergusson","URLname":"alex","Picture":{"Url":"d2d1117d023f81739aa7681fb60b98e92208d8c7.jpeg","Alt":""}},"Slug":"the-ultimate-one-week-istanbul-itinerary-and-guide","Themes":[{"Id":938,"Name":"Art & Design","Slug":"art-design"},{"Id":943,"Name":"History","Slug":"history"},{"Id":944,"Name":"Local Culture","Slug":"local-culture"}],"Name":"The Ultimate 5 Days Istanbul Itinerary and Guide","Cover":{"Url":"cb33d105cb7eaa59a912fac1df5e9c86d1562588.jpeg"},"Description":"vaoila dsvdvsdvsdv","FromDate":1480118400000,"NbrViews":1405,"NumCheckin":38,"NumPhoto":209,"NumLike":203,"NumComment":24,"Tigr":61.808134736842,"Published":true,"MapLines":true,"ToDate":1511005270,"DatesKnown":true,"Duration":358,"CreatedAt":"2017-07-17T09:05:47+02:00","UpdatedAt":"2018-04-02T15:37:34+02:00","Disable":false,"GooglestaticUrl":"the-ultimate-one-week-istanbul-itinerary-and-guide-travel-itinerary-1509033384.png","MonthViews":0}
```

if I do

```
 {{trip.id}} {{trip.name}}
```

or trip.anything i have no results but I know that these attributes are not empty.

this issue appears only when I used wepback with angularJS@1.5.8 in SF4 project.

Any Ideas?

Comment: what about `{{trip.Id}}` and `{{trip.Profile.Name}} `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Json suggests, you should do,

```
 {{trip.Id}} {{trip.Profile.Id}} {{trip.profile.Name}}
```